# OAuth in Play Framework 2.2.2

Tags: oauth, playframework

I have been looking for some documentation around how to do OAuth in the Play framework (version 2.2.2) and I can't really find anything. I read in one place that it has been deprecated but I haven't been able to find anything about this either. Does anyone know? I want to connect to the Twitter API and make some requests for data in my application.

Answer (score 1):

You can find examples of OAuth with Play Framework on these open source projects:

- [securesocial](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial)
- [play-silhouette](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette)
- [play-authenticate](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate)

Answer (score -1):

It's supported and actually pretty straight forward.

Here's an OAuth authorization example directly from the [Play Docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaOAuth):

```
  object Twitter extends Controller {

  val KEY = ConsumerKey("xxxxx", "xxxxx")

  val TWITTER = OAuth(ServiceInfo(
    "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
    "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
    "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize", KEY),
    false)

  def authenticate = Action { request =>
    request.queryString.get("oauth_verifier").flatMap(_.headOption).map { verifier =>
      val tokenPair = sessionTokenPair(request).get
      // We got the verifier; now get the access token, store it and back to index
      TWITTER.retrieveAccessToken(tokenPair, verifier) match {
        case Right(t) => {
          // We received the authorized tokens in the OAuth object - store it before we proceed
          Redirect(routes.Application.index).withSession("token" -> t.token, "secret" -> t.secret)
        }
        case Left(e) => throw e
      }
    }.getOrElse(
      TWITTER.retrieveRequestToken("http://localhost:9000/auth") match {
        case Right(t) => {
          // We received the unauthorized tokens in the OAuth object - store it before we proceed
          Redirect(TWITTER.redirectUrl(t.token)).withSession("token" -> t.token, "secret" -> t.secret)
        }
        case Left(e) => throw e
      })
  }

  def sessionTokenPair(implicit request: RequestHeader): Option[RequestToken] = {
    for {
      token <- request.session.get("token")
      secret <- request.session.get("secret")
    } yield {
      RequestToken(token, secret)
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to sign request, you can do it like this:

```
WS.url(s"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json")
   .sign(OAuthCalculator(Key, RequestToken(token, tokenSecret)))
   .get
```

Please note that the above is for OAuth 1.0. OAuth2 is very easy to implement without a dedicated library that why the Play folks left it out.

Comment: the author asked for advice - and you tell him it "is very easy to implement" ~ this isn't very constructive.